# How to Append file via java nio writer?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to Write Data in File(GCS BUCKET FILE) in Append Mode But I am Getting Error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: APPEND
```

The Code Which I Wrote is:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("gs://test"));
                   byte[] data = "hello world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                   Path path = fs.getPath("/Testing");
                   Files.write(path, data,StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND );
```

Is it a Bug or I am Missing Something ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, none of the popular public cloud file storages support appending to objects (only overwriting), and Google Cloud Storage is no exception. E.g. see similar question about [S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object) and [Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304466/how-do-i-append-to-a-file-in-an-azure-storage-file-share).